# What is the algorithm to approximate value using the Lagrange form of the remainder

Tags: taylor-expansion

$\log (1.0008)$ is actually the problem. Accuracy is $<10^{-7}$
The second problem is to solve it for $\log(0.9992)$

Comment: Your main problem is, that this isn't a question. Would you mind to get all the information into the body of your question (not just title/tags): what you are talking about, what you tried and where you got stuck. Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to find approximate value of the logarithm using the Lagrange form the remainder.

Comment: Erm, sorry... did I mention "into the body of your question"? BTW, a Lagrange form of the remainder exists for polynomial interpolation, too. If you really want an answer, don't let people guess what you are asking, please!